How to specify a default local file for an includes?
I have a Gitlab pipeline and I want to include another pipeline. I want to run it multiple times, but with different inputs each time. Something like this:
include:
  - local: 'my-pipeline.yml'
    inputs:
      param1: 'value 1'
  - local: 'my-pipeline.yml'
    inputs:
      param1: 'value 2'

Since the file path will be the same for all items in include, is there a way to set it as a default value so I don't need to repeat local: 'my-pipeline.yml' each time?
I want the end result to look something like this:
include:
  - inputs:
      param1: 'value 1'
  - inputs:
      param1: 'value 2'


There's no specific mechanism for specifying a default filename. But to just avoid repeating yourself and define the filename only once, you can use YAML anchors.
.default_include: &include-defaults
  local: 'my-pipeline.yml'

include:
  - inputs:
      foo: bar
    <<: *include-defaults
  - inputs:
      bar: baz
    <<: *include-defaults

